# How to represent "And" in Python behave step definition

Tags: bdd, python-behave

For example i have following scenario in a feature file

```
Scenario: A Scenario
    Given a precondition
    When step 1
    And step 2
    Then step 3
```

In Ruby i can write stepdefinition for above scenario as following:

```
Given("a precondition") do

end

When("step 1") do

end

And("step 2") do

end

Then("step 3") do

end
```

I have to implement this using Python Behave and i am confused about **And** implementation annotation in stepdefinition for this, i did not find @and in the examples i referred.

```
@given("a precondition")
def given_implementation(context)
    pass

@when("step 1")
def when_implementation(context)
    pass

#which annotation to use for and??
def and_implementation(context)
    pass

@then("step 3")
def then_implementation(context):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`And` merely inherits from whatever the previous step was. From the [docs](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gherkin.html#and-but),

[image: From website]

So in your case, you'd want to change your step implementation to the following:

```
@given("a precondition")
def given_implementation(context)
    pass

@when("step 1")
def when_implementation(context)
    pass

@when("step 2") <--------------------- Changed to this!
def and_implementation(context)
    pass

@then("step 3")
def then_implementation(context):
    pass
```

Comment: So, if i use And in Gherkin for better readability and use @when in corresponding step definition, will it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Type @step instead of @when. And it will be universal. It means that the same step definition might be used with other keywords like given, when, then